# Custom plugin settings link doesn't append current class to menu item when visited? Why?

Tags: php, plugin-development, add-menu-page

So I've created a custom setting link on my plugin listing, that takes the user to the plugin settings. However, it doesn't seem to be working as I would expect it to and I'm not sure why.

To clarify, the link is added, and it does redirect. So the basic functionality is as I would expect. It's a visual error, I.e indication to the user which page they are on in the admin sidebar menu.

---

**Expected Behaviour:**

- User clicks settings link.
- User is taken to `'wp-admin/admin.php?page=apwb_settings'` page.
- Side bar menu `<li>` and `<a>` has `class="current"` appended.

**Actual Behavior:**

- User clicks settings link.
- User is taken to `'wp-admin/admin.php?page=apwb_settings'` page.
- Side bar menu `<li>` and `<a>` remains unchanged.

---

**My Registered Setting...**

```php
/** 
 * Register the settings page.
 * 
 * @package     apwb/postal-pricing
 * @since       1.0.0
*/
function apwb_settings_page() {
    add_options_page(
        __( 'Postal Pricing Settings', 'postal-pricing' ),
        __( 'Postal Pricing Settings', 'postal-pricing' ),
        'manage_options',
        'apwb_settings',
        function() {
            ?>
            <div id="apwb-settings"></div>
            <?php
        },
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', __NAMESPACE__ . '\apwb_settings_page' );
```

**My plugin links amendment...**

```php
/** 
 * Add settings link to plugin listing.
 * 
 * @package     apwb/postal-pricing
 * @since       1.0.0
*/
function apwb_settings_link( $links ) : array {
    $label = esc_html__( 'Settings', 'postal-pricing' );
    $slug  = 'apwb_settings';
    $admin_url = admin_url('admin.php?page=' . $slug);

    array_unshift( 
        $links, 
        "<a href='$admin_url'>$label</a>" 
    );

    return $links;
}
add_filter( 'plugin_action_links_' . plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), __NAMESPACE__ . '\apwb_settings_link' );
```

**My Question...**
How does WordPress typically handle this behavior? Is it something I can hook into? Or will I have to write a custom solution? **(*I really don't want to add more js if I can help it.*)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed your `apwb_settings_page()` function is adding the "Postal Pricing Settings" submenu using `add_options_page()`, and the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_options_page/#more-information) stated that: <sub>(bold formatting added by me)</sub>

> - This function is a simple wrapper for a call to  [add_submenu_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/), passing the received arguments and **specifying ‘`options-general.php`‘ as the  `$parent_slug`  argument**. This means the new options page will be added as a sub menu to the Settings menu.

And that also means, in your `apwb_settings_link()` function, `$admin_url` (or your settings link) should actually *link to or use `options-general.php`* and **not** `admin.php`:

- **Incorrect:** `$admin_url = admin_url('admin.php?page=' . $slug);`
- **Correct:** `$admin_url = admin_url('options-general.php?page=' . $slug);`
- **Even better:** Use [`menu_page_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/menu_page_url/), e.g. `$admin_url = menu_page_url( $slug, false );`

The "Incorrect" above will actually load the correct "Postal Pricing Settings" admin page, but the "Postal Pricing Settings" **submenu** (under the "Settings" menu) *will not* be highlighted because the parent file is *not* `options-general.php`. So actually, you just needed to ensure your setting link uses the correct admin page URL. :)

Comment: Beautifully answered Sally, thanks for clearing that up. 